# What do these codes do?

Tags: c

I saw this source code in a book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *delivery = "";
    int thick = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d: t")) != EOF)
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'd':
                delivery = optarg;
                break;

            case 't':
                thick = 1;
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg);
                return 1;
        }

        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;

        if (thick)
            puts("Thick Crust.");

        if (delivery[0])
            printf("To be deliverd %s\n", delivery);

        puts("Ingredients: ");

        for (count = 0; count < argc; count++)
            puts(argv[count]);

    return 0;
}
```

I can understand the entire source except:

```
argc -= optind;
argv += optind;
```

I know what is argc and argv, but what happen them in these two lines, what is "optind"
Explain me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getopt` library provides several function to help parsing the command line arguments.

When you call `getopt` it "eats" a variable number of arguments (depending on the type of command line option); the number of arguments "eaten" is indicated in the `optind` global variable.

Your code adjusts `argv` and `argc` using `optind` to jump the arguments just consumed.

Answer (score 3):

it's a global variable used by `getopt`.

From the manual:

> The getopt() function parses the command-line arguments. Its arguments
>   argc and argv are the argument count and array as passed to the main()
>   function on program invocation.
>
> The variable optind is the index of the next element to be processed
>   in argv. The system initializes this value to 1.

That code just updates argc and argv to point to the rest of the arguments (`-` options skipped).

Comment: Or, if you have installed the correct manpages, `man optind` will give you this same information.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the how :**

optind is the number of elements of argv which will be ignored after this code :

```
argc -= optind; // reduces the argument number by optind 
argv += optind; // changes the pointer to go optind items after the first one
```

argc (the count) is reduced by optind

and the pointer to the first element of argv is upgraded accordingly.

**Regarding the why :**

See Karoly's answer.

Answer (score 0):

while running this code you might execute it as ./executable_file:name -d some_argument

When getopt is called it starts scanning what is written in command line. argc = 3, argv[0]=./executable_file:name argv[1]=-d argv[2]=some_argument .
getopt will get the option d that time optind = 2 that is the index of the next i.e argv[2].
Hence optind+argv will point to argv[2].

In general optind will have the index of the next.